# Pass a dropdown index value as value for an enum field

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a panel with a dropdown; which I use to set a field in my project.

```
public class projectclass
{
    public enum mainpriority
    {
        basic,
        urgent,
        critical
    };
    public mainpriority _priorityfield { get; set;}


}
```

The project class use an enum for this field, so to populate the dropdown I do this, to populate it:

```
mydropdown.options.Clear();
foreach (projectclass._priorityfield priority in projectclass._priorityfield.GetValues(typeof(projectclass._priorityfield)))
{
    mydropdown.options.Add( new Dropdown.OptionData() {text = priority.ToString()});
}
```

This allow me to display the field in the dropbox, for each instance of the projectclass.
All is good in this direction, but if I want to do the opposite (change the value in the dropdown, and change the class field accordingly), I can't make it work.

The main issue is that I try to assign to the class, the value as int (which is what I get back from the dropdown.value() method), but VS tell me that it is not possible to set a _priorityfield type with an int type.

Isn't the enum, equivalent to 0,1,2.....n; so you can either use "basic" or 0 as value?

This is what I do to set the class instance value, from the dropdown, using the onValueChanged delegate

```
private void UpdatePriority(Dropdown priority)
{
    int tempvalue = priority.value;
    projectclass_instance1._priorityfield = tempvalue;
}
```

I assumed that I can pass an int, but VS says that is not possible. I could map each value of the dropdown to an entry in the enum, but I am not sure that it is actually the best solution.

Comment: you have to cast it : ``(mainpriority)tempvalue``

Comment: That's it; casting it will remove the error. It won't update the original value in the class instance but this is a different issue; I can work that out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ehsan for the solution.

The error is because I need to cast the int value as enum type, so the value will be correctly recognized.